# AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'show_credits_heading'

Tags: python, pygame

I have made a simple app that lists the credits of a project I'm working on, it's just something fun I wanted to do that was out of the box. However when I run the program an error shows up. It says that "AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'show_credits_heading'" Which I have no idea why that is coming. Here is the code:

```
# Menu
Menu_Font = pygame.font.Font("8-BIT WONDER.TTF", 45)
Menu_HeadingX = 290
Menu_HeadingY = 70

Text_Font = pygame.font.Font("8-BIT WONDER.TTF", 25)

start_x, start_y = Menu_HeadingX, Menu_HeadingY+150
options_x, options_y = Menu_HeadingX, Menu_HeadingY+200
credits_x, credits_y = Menu_HeadingX, Menu_HeadingY+250

class credits_menu():
def show_credits_heading():
    Credits_Heading = Menu_Font.render("Credits", True, (255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(Credits_Heading, (Menu_HeadingX, Menu_HeadingY))

def show_code_credit():
    Code_Credit = Text_Font.render("All Code: By Me", True, (255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(Sound_Option, (start_x, start_y))

def show_idea_credit():
    Idea_Credit = Text_Font.render("Idea By Me", True, (255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(Sound_Option, (options_x, options_y))
     
def show_img_credit():
    Img_Credit = Text_Font.render("Images: Taken from google", True, (255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(Sound_Option, (credits_x, credits_y))
```

Main Problem is in:

```
while credits_menu:
    screen.fill((0,0,0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running, playing, credits_menu, options_menu = False, False, False, False

    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    credits_menu.show_credits_heading()
    credits_menu.show_code_credit()
    credits_menu.show_idea_credit()
    credits_menu.show_img_credit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this line:

```
        running, playing, credits_menu, options_menu = False, False, False, False
```

you set `credits_menu` to `False`

This overrides its earlier definition as a class

Comment: Yes, but that is only if the quit button is pressed. (The top right button on the screen to close an app) So I can't really remove that.

Comment: You are using the same name `credits_menu` for two different purposes; use a different name for one of them

Comment: Hey! I realized you were right! I renamed the class "Credits" as there was confusion between the variable and the class. Thanks a lot @Jiří Baum

Answer (score 0):

So the main answer for such kinds of questions is to check what you are referencing. In this case, I accidentally referenced the **variable** `credits_menu` instead of the **class** `credits_menu` because both were labeled the same so the python runner got confused and took the variable instead which did not have the defined functions.

So the corrected code would be:

```
class credits():
def show_credits_heading():
    Credits_Heading = Menu_Font.render("Credits", True, (255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(Credits_Heading, (Menu_HeadingX, Menu_HeadingY))

def show_code_credit():
    Sound_Option = Credit_Font.render("All Code: By Me", True, (255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(Sound_Option, (SCREEN_WIDTH/2, start_y))

def show_idea_credit():
    Sound_Option = Credit_Font.render("Idea By Me(my mom helped a bit too)", True, (255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(Sound_Option, (SCREEN_WIDTH/2, options_y))
     
def show_img_credit():
    Sound_Option = Credit_Font.render("Images: Taken from google", True, (255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(Sound_Option, (SCREEN_WIDTH/2, credits_y))

while credits_menu:
screen.fill((0,0,0))

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running, playing, credits_menu, options_menu = False, False, False, False

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
            if state == "Back":
                running, playing, credits_menu, options_menu = False, True, False, False

screen.fill((0,0,0))
credits.show_credits_heading()
credits.show_code_credit()
credits.show_idea_credit()
credits.show_img_credit()

#Update Screen
pygame.display.update()
clock.tick(60)
```